# Перевод строки в объект

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

Имеется строка `"(Word или (it и then) или word2) и Word3"`. Необходимо эту строку трансформировать в объект: `{and: [{ or: ["Word", { and: ["it", "then"] }, "Word2"] }, "Word3"]}`. Имеется реализация рекурсией, но она не полна и может работать только с массивом:

```
type OperationsRussian = 'ИЛИ' | 'И'

const LogicalOperations: Record<OperationsRussian, Operations> = {
  ИЛИ: 'or',
  И: 'and',
}

export const preparationIncludedPhrases = (
  phrases: unknown
): Record<string, object> => {

  const firstValue = Array.isArray(phrases[0])
    ? preparationIncludedPhrases(phrases[0])
    : phrases[0]
  const operation = phrases[1]
  const secondValue = Array.isArray(phrases[2])
    ? preparationIncludedPhrases(phrases[2])
    : phrases[2]

  return {
    [LogicalOperations[operation as OperationsRussian]]: [
      firstValue,
      secondValue,
    ],
  }
}

preparationIncludedPhrases([['apple', 'И', ['tiger', 'ИЛИ', 'lion']], 'ИЛИ', 'word'])
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: могут ли разные операции быть внутри одной скобки? `"Word или it и then или word2"` - если возможна такая строка - то какой ожидается результат?

Comment: В данном случае ожидается результат ```{or: ["word", {and: ["it", "then"]}, "word2"]}```